# Custom model manager that uses model methods in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

in my model, i have 3 methods. i want to use `get_days_remaining` method to get all policies expiring in 30 days.

```
Class TravelPolicy(models.Model):
    ....
    ....

def get_period_of_cover(self):
    some logic
def get_days_left_to_run(self):
    some logic

def get_days_remaining(self):
    return float(self.get_period_of_cover()) - float(self.get_days_left_to_run())
```

currently doing `TravelPolicy.objects.all()` returns over 10,000 policies, while i might policies in order of few 100s expiring in next 30 days. How can i get only the policies expiring in 30 days using `get_days_remaining` method within my views before passing it to html file ?

Comment: we need to know the `"some logic"` part detailed to answer your question - but in principle, by writting some logic you will be able to achieve what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like the following in your view (using iterator will not load all the policies in memory):

```
my_policies = [i for i in TravelPolicy.objects.iterator() if i.get_days_remaining() < 30]
```